# Android 2.1 bug getting time?

Tags: c#, datetime, xamarin.android

I have developed an application on Monodroid and I have encountered the following error.

When I do `DateTime.Now` the value is wrongly saved on my database for an Android 2.1 device. The time saved corresponds always to GMT time, not the local time for the device. On the other hand, if I run my app on an Android 2.2 device the time saved on my database is OK. What the hell happens?

I appreciate some help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a bug.

For compatibility, use `DateTime.UtcNow`. It should always return GMT.

```
DateTime nowutc = DateTime.UtcNow;
DateTime now = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(nowutc, TimeZoneInfo.Utc, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id));
```

Comment: DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime();